# How to install Ubuntu on Windows machine while still maintaining seamless boot to Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I am currently running Windows 7 as the only OS and I am wondering if it is possible to install Ubuntu as secondary OS, which would only be accessible via some explicitly called boot menu - by that I mean that after I am done with installing Ubuntu and setting this up, if I restart PC it would boot exactly like it does now, when only Windows 7 is installed.
If I would want to access Ubuntu, I would have to press some key to bring up boot menu before Windows loads (or just go straight to Ubuntu without any menu actually). 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would rather install Ubuntu as a virtual machine within Windows. In this way Windows will always boot at first, and you can start Ubuntu als needed. As additional benefit, you have parallel access to both systems at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly this in a machine with more than on physical hard disk or SSD.  I used BIOS settings to set the drive without Windows to primary, installed (carefully!) Kubuntu on the hard disk that was then reporting "No operating system found", and used boot menu to access Windows when I wanted it.  I don't recommend this, though; it'd be preferred to set GRUB to start Windows by default with a reasonably short delay.